# eclipse port occupying error on startup

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, system-administration

I am getting this error while starting eclipse. I am using eclipse on windows 7 
**"There is a process already using the admin port 4848 -- it probably is another instance of a GlassFish server.

Command start-domain failed."**
I have searched and found that if i put mny hostname against 127.0.0.1 then this problem can be resolve but my problem is that i can't place my hostname in my host file due to our organization internal network security and i can't even edit this file.So i want that this glassfish server stops allocating 4848 port and starts working on another port.
Please help as i got stuck in this issue.
Thanks

Comment: Why you talk about hostname when your problem is about the port being used? Your problem is that port 4848 is used by another process. Use `netstat` to find out.

Comment: I dont know but only this solution is written everywhere. I have checked port 4848 and it is bind with the process java.exe. So what should i do now?

Comment: Kill java.exe process. Probably it's a zombie of a previous GlassFish server instance.

Comment: should i kill? Would it not start again when my machine restart?

Comment: So you have a standalone glassfish AND an Eclipse-embedded one? Then that's your probelem. Did you recently install a Glassfish Eclipse plugin?

Comment: It should not start automatically when you start the OS if you didn't configure it to do so. If you did, remove that option. Or change that server instance's binding port.

Comment: yes i have installed it recently @MarkoTopolnik

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse plugin contributes its own Glassfish instance that runs only as long as Eclipse runs. Uninstalling your standalone copy is probably a good solution for you. If not, reconfigure the standalone copy to use a different admin port.

A simple Google search will cover that for you. [Here](https://blogs.oracle.com/openroad/entry/changing_default_glassfish_port_numbers)'s what I have found as the top hit.